# How to count specific nodes in an XML string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, count

I have a string like that:

```
text = <<-XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

    <url>
      <loc>https://www.my9.jp/LanLT/index.cfm?fuseaction=job.detail&amp;sgtno=Job-000002</loc>
      <lastmod>2019-10-04</lastmod>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
      <loc>https://www.my9.jp/LanLT/index.cfm?fuseaction=job.detail&amp;sgtno=samnangtest002</loc>
      <lastmod>2019-10-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
      <loc>https://www.my9.jp/LanLT/index.cfm?fuseaction=job.detail&amp;sgtno=Job-000006</loc>
      <lastmod>2019-10-04</lastmod>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
  </urlset>
XML
```

I want to count number of substrings that begin with `<url>` and end with  `</url>`. In this string, for example, the result is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text.scan(/<url>.*?<\/url>/m).size
```

`m` stands for multiline.

The regex pattern searches for stuff enveloped by `<url>` and `</url>`.

Comment: Regex for parsing xml - arghh!

Answer (score 2):

Use right tool for the job. Tool for parsing HTML or XML data - [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/)

```
require 'nokogiri'

count = Nokogiri::XML.parse(text).root.children.count {|node| node.name == "url" }
```

If you want calculate all `<url>` nodes from grandchildren as well(recursively), then try `traverse` method (regex approach will not work for this case)

```
count = 0
Nokogiri::XML.parse(text).traverse { |node| count += 1 if node.name == "url" }

puts count # => 3
```

You should not use regex for parsing xml data. Regex wasn't designed for that and is error prone.

Comment: Or `Nokogiri::XML(text).xpath('//xmlns:url').count`